# Delete a text line. I dont know where to do

Tags: line

i dont want to have the yellow marked line, i dont know where its from.
I cant see in my code where it is generated and why.
I just have one file.

[image: screenshot from PDF]

[image: screenshot from ma code]

Comment: It probably comes from the `scrpage2` package or its `automark` option.

Comment: please, insert a MWE which demonstrates your problem.  I was not able, to recreate the problem.  Maybe you have to run LaTeX a second time?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something different of what you show in your preamble. However,
use it this way:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}% Only for demo
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    
\newpage
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```